# Data tree in CSS with multiple parents

Tags: html, css

At work I have been asked to make up a hierarchical data tree (in CSS HTML) showing who is in charge of who and who is in charge group A and group B and so on... I have found this great data tree in codepen http://codepen.io/chuongdang/pen/lcnsC but it only allows for one parent to be the parent of a group where I need it to be two or maybe even three. Unfortunately I can't post images yet but here is a link of what I would like the structure to be more like - [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB6Tk.jpg) What would I have to change in the CSS/HTML to have multiple parent nodes?

Thanks

Comment: So it's pretty easy, did you tried?

Comment: Yup, I tried putting two parent wrappers around the children but that didn't really work and I tried a couple of other different li ul variations but no joy?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<div class="tree">
<ul>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Parent1</a>
        <a href="#">Parent2</a>   //Add any Number of Parents
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Child</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Child</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks that sort of works except that when I add 
            `<li>
                <a href="#">Child 1</a>
                <a href="#">Child 2</a>
                <a href="#">Child 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>`

then only the last child link will highlight its childeren?

Comment: I am not getting you what you wants in your comment as you have asked for multiple parents with child i have posted a sample code for that you can implement it , Possibly you wants something else, if it is plz reply me.

Comment: So this is what I have in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j67Nk/) and this [image](http://imgur.com/GRTyxaD) is what I'm trying to get to, not as easy as I probably made it sound , sorry.